# Bad SwiftUI performance when scrolling a text view with ~1000 lines

Tags: swiftui

I've created a simple SwiftUI macOS app that allows users to import a text file and then displays the text. When importing a decently sized text file (1500 lines) the view will hang for several seconds after scrolling using the scrollbar. Using the profiler I can see the CPU usage is very high and has Severe Hangs. Any ideas the issue with my code that might be causing this? Thank you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  private var loggingView = LoggingView()
  
  var body: some View {
    loggingView
  }
}

struct LoggingView: View {
  @StateObject private var model = LoggingModel()
  var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView {
      if model.data.isEmpty {
        Text("Add a file to begin.")
      } else {
        Text(model.data).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
    }
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(action: model.addFilePath) {
          Text("New File")
          Label("Import", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class LoggingModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var data: String = ""
  
  func addFilePath() {
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    dialog.title                   = "Choose a .txt file";
    dialog.allowedContentTypes     = [.text]
    
    if (dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
      let result = dialog.url // Pathname of the file
      
      guard let result else {
        return
      }
      
      load(file: result.path)
    }
  }
  
  func load(file: String) {
    do {
      let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: file)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.data = contents
      }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LazyVStack` in the `ScrollView` and modifier your code as follows to achieve the desired effect:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        // Your views here
    }
}
```

By using `LazyVStack` within the `ScrollView`:

- You can create a vertically growing stack that generates items only as needed.
- This approach improves performance by rendering only the visible items on the screen, especially when dealing with large data sets.

If you want a horizontally arranged stack, you can use `LazyHStack` instead.

Similarly, there is `LazyHGrid` available for grid-like layouts.

Comment: This answer gets you a lot of the way there. I would also review [Demystify SwiftUI performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/) where the go into some detail on this problem and point out some potential gotchas.

Comment: Thank you this helped! In addition to this I had to create a new view for each line so that SwiftUI could optimize by hiding the out-of-frame views.