# How to deal with swiftui extra long text displayed as blank?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

About 100,000 text, can be displayed using TextField However, there are other problems that do not want to be used, using Text is just to display a blank, but the position is occupied ScrollView can scroll. Is there a big god to help solve it, the code is very simple, there is nothing special？

```
VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 3){
            ScrollView{
                if let cnt = current?.content{
                    Text(cnt)
                }
            }
        }
```

i try add .lineLimit(nil),.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
None of them worked

[I used another way, reading markdown files. The result is still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqO3.jpg)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
       var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 3){
            markdownFileView()
        }
    }
}

struct markdownFileView: View {
    let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "md")
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVStack{
                // Show the markdown here
                Text(try! AttributedString(
                    contentsOf: filepath!,
                    options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(
                        interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace
                    )))
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct CustomPickerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a ```LazyVStack``` instead of a ```VStack```. See also [Bad SwiftUI performance when scrolling a text view with ~1000 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76503554/20386264).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad SwiftUI performance when scrolling a text view with ~1000 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503554/bad-swiftui-performance-when-scrolling-a-text-view-with-1000-lines)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this

```
struct markdownFileView: View {
    
    @State var textArray: [String] = []
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                ForEach(textArray, id: \.self) { text in
                    Text(try! AttributedString(
                        markdown: text,
                                        options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(
                                            interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace
                                        ))).textSelection(.enabled)

 
                }
            }
           
        }.onAppear{
            let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "md")
            let text = try! String(contentsOf: filepath!)
            let forCount = text.count/50000
            for i in 0...forCount {
                var to = (i+1)*50000
                let form = i*50000
                if to>text.count{
                    to = text.count
                }
                textArray.append(text[form..<to])
            }
        }
    }
}
```